# UIWebView clear selection

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm looking for a way to clear the user selection on text in a web view.  Or any other view for that matter.  Anyone come across this?

Comment: I have a custom UIWebView that only shows internal packaged content. That subclassed web view has an option to highlight or annotate the text.  When said highlight or annotation is completed I need to clear the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem when i build an EPub3 reader (which supports highlights). To resolve, i find the selection view from my webview and remove it from superview.

```
UIView *selectionView = [self findSelectionView:yourWebView];
if (selectionView != nil) {
    [selectionView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(UIView *)findSelectionView: (UIView *)uiView {
    if([[[view class] description] matches:@"^UI.*SelectionView$"]){
        return view;
    }

    for(UIView* subview in view.subviews){
        UIView * rs = [self findSelectionUIViewFrom: subview];
        if(rs)return rs;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert Javascript code into the webview. Or force a reload?

Is this necessary to do in iOS. Can't you do this through the HTML/webpage? Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly.

Comment: I tried to clear the selection by injecting window.getSelection().clearRange();   That had no effect.  In either case when I perform an operation on the text, the same text remains selected in the browser, but iOS wraps the entire containing paragraph with it's own selection box.  It looks confusing to the user.

Comment: would it be feasible to reload the view?

Comment: I feel like reloading the web view every time would be bad for user experience.

Comment: I don't know of any javascript that will clear selections that would work in your case. Sorry.